# Calculated column doesnt work - Language issue?

Tags: calculated-column

I found this nice calculated column, [Days since list item was created](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88849/days-since-list-item-was-created)

On the demo tenant it works awesome. So i tried it at the production version. Here is the default language Dutch but everything is now English.

When i use this code: `=DATEVALUE(TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")) - DATEVALUE(TEXT([Created],"mm/dd/yyyy"))`

The output is: #Value! When i check the column, all the words are in Dutch. When i changed it back to English, i automatically changed to Dutch.

Is there a solution for this? I tried to write the code in Dutch but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Try `;` instead of `,`. In some language packages `,` is reserved for other usage. However, at least with SharePoint's PnP (using SharePoint Online) the calculated column usage with custom language packs is reported as a bug in here https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/1236.

Answer (score 2):

Found it, simple mistake :)

`=DATEVALUE(TEXT(NOW(),"dd/mm/yyyy")) - DATEVALUE(TEXT([Created],"dd/mm/yyyy"))`

I changed dd/mm and now it works.