# Column days pending - how to update automatically

Tags: calculated-column

I have made a few differents options for days pending with SharePoint.
I would like to know, how many days a item is open.

First i tried this solution: https://www.solwebsolutions.com/blog/entry/calculate-age-of-sharepoint-list-items I tried this solution, i deleted the today columns. After this, "SharePoint automatically refers "Today" (which has been deleted now) as the today’s date in the formula calculation." but that don't work.

Second option: =DATEVALUE(TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy")) - DATEVALUE(TEXT([Created],"mm/dd/yyyy"))
[Days since list item was created](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88849/days-since-list-item-was-created)

Both option dont update the item by them self. Do you know why it don't work? I tested both option on two differents tenants.

Hopefully we can fix this :)

Answer (score 0):

The fields in the list view will only be updated when somebody modifies a listitem, so that approach will not work. One option could be to display the items somewhere using a search resultat web part, and in the item display template calculate and show the age of the item

Comment: Sounds good, do you have a tutorial for this.

Comment: Something like this perhaps? https://searchexplained.com/display-template-for-tasks-in-sharepoint-2013-office-365/

Answer (score 0):

here is a Javascript solution you may want to look into. It's annoying and inconvenient that SharePoint will not update list fields automatically, but rather whenever its been updated manually or with non-OOTB solutions... Let me know if this helps!

[Automatically calculate Todays date in SharePoint List](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0c3fc40a-605d-406d-89aa-0b453aea7302/automatically-calculate-todays-date-in-sharepoint-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

---

A. Save the following code into a js file(AgeInDays.js).

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {        
        "AgeInDays": { "View": ShowAgeInDays}
    };

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function ShowAgeInDays(ctx) {
    var created= ctx.CurrentItem.Created;        
    return countDay(created);
}
function countDay(date){
    var b = new Date(date);
    var e = new Date();
    var dif = e.getTime() - b.getTime();
    var day = Math.floor(dif / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return day; 
}
```

B. Upload the js file into the Site Assets library.

C. Edit the list view page and add the text below into the JS Link property in the web part editor.

```
`~site/SiteAssets/AgeInDays.js`
```

Comment: Do we need to created AgeInDays column as a number datatype for this

Answer (score 0):

I used this method, flow.

https://sharepointlibrarian.com/2017/12/08/use-microsoft-flow-to-create-a-today-column-for-use-in-sharepoint-list-calculations/

The flow runs perfect. It was 5 mins work to solve this with flow. 
Hopefully someone will use this option too.

Comment: Doesn't it causes havoc in the version history ?